# copy and paste from csv file to excel file

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I modified a piece of code that opens a .csv file, copies a selected range and pastes it in a selected cell in an excel worksheet.

I am having trouble selecting the next range in the .csv file to paste in the excel file. It only works for the first range (E2:E25).

I want it to select the next range (B2:B25) from the .csv file, copy/paste, but it only selects from the excel file. How do I fix that? Thanks.

```
Option Explicit                               

Sub copy2()
Dim FilesToOpen
Dim wkbAll As Workbook
Dim wkbTemp As Workbook
Dim newSheet As Worksheet
FilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Text Files to Open")
    Set wkbTemp = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilesToOpen, Format:=4)
    wkbTemp.Sheets(1).Cells.copy
    Range("E2:E25").Select
    Selection.copy
    Windows("Petty Cash Form (test).xls").Activate
    Range("H10").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False


    Range("B2:B25").Select
    Selection.copy
    Windows("Petty Cash Form (test).xls").Activate
    Range("B10").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    wkbTemp.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: DId you code this yourself or did you blend this with copied code and Macro Recorder. I'm asking because if you made this yourself I would ask you to define the sheets to make it easier to solve your issue.

Comment: I blended the copy/paste bit from the macro recorder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your VBA macro add the line:  `wkbTemp.Sheets(1).Activate` (see 'Activate Source Worksheet):

```
Option Explicit

Sub copy2()
Dim FilesToOpen
Dim wkbAll As Workbook
Dim wkbTemp As Workbook
Dim newSheet As Worksheet
FilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Text Files to Open")
    Set wkbTemp = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilesToOpen, Format:=4)
    wkbTemp.Sheets(1).Cells.copy
    Range("E2:E25").Select
    Selection.copy
    Windows("Petty Cash Form (test).xls").Activate
    Range("H10").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

  'Activate Source Worksheet
  wkbTemp.Sheets(1).Activate    

    Range("B2:B25").Select
    Selection.copy
    Windows("Petty Cash Form (test).xls").Activate
    Range("B10").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    wkbTemp.Close

End Sub
```

Hope this may help.

Comment: You are welcome! Please accept the answer if satisfied. Good luck with your project. Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat of a rudimentary answer but I would suggest following the VBA hierarchy in order to select specific ranges.

```
workbook.worksheet.range
```

I think if you defined the worksheets then used

```
wrktemp.Sheets("sheet name").Range("E2:E25")
```

I believe this will help in pursuit of your problem